# How to keep Snowflake connection alive in python

Tags: python, flask, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a database in Snowflake and using [Snowflake's Python Connector](https://pypi.org/project/snowflake-connector-python) I am accessing the database and doing database queries from Flask server as below:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='username',
password='pass',
account='account',
client_session_keep_alive=True
)
cs = ctx.cursor()

try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print("Successfully connected to snowflake version: {}".format(one_row[0]))
    cs.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Snowflake connection error: {}".format(e))
    cs.close()
```

I have defined the snowflake connection session as a global **ctx** variable to be accessible from any Flask API function.

After starting the Flask server, everything works fine but if no API calls are made for continuously few hours then it throws an error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 390114 (08001): Authentication token has expired.  The user must authenticate again.
```

As you can see I have kept the `client_session_keep_alive=True` parameter in Snowflake connect API to keep the session alive but still somehow this fails.
I explored about this issue but did not get any conclusive information.
So I want to know how can I keep the database connection session alive or do I have to create new connection session for each query?

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: do you solved this issue , i.am also getting this issue, please write an sol. If you got the solution

Comment: The `client_session_keep_alive` parameter should keep the session open. If it doesn't work we need to understand why, therefore getting the connector's log is important. Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [community note](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Authentication-token-has-expired-The-user-must-authenticate-again)
there is not much you can do other than start issuing dummy sqls every now and then, however i noticed there is a [CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters) parameter that you might test first [see this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r0000BzRrstCQC/need-to-understand-clientsessionkeepaliveheartbeatfrequency)